# What's a good method for writing fixed width field files?

Tags: perl

I need to write a file that is probably being interpreted by something like RPG IV on an AS/400 (but I don't know that). The file will be created by reading data from our MySQL database and then writing it in the specified format. It could be quite large ( potentially measured in GB but haven't determined yet ). Right now I'm thinking Perl's built in `format` might actually be my best bet, because things like Xslate, and Template Toolkit are more designed for things that aren't fixed width (HTML). My only concern there is that `format` doesn't appear to have conditionals and it looks like I may need them (I found a format left justified if field A is set, right justified and padded if not)

Comment: Another possibility is [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl6::Form) which is Perl6's version of `format` for Perl5. I'm not sure about your comment about conditionals, but this does more than format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other possibilities that come to mind are [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) and the [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) family of functions.

I don't think `pack` supports right-justified text, so that wouldn't be an option.

That leaves (s)printf.  You can build format specifiers programatically to support your conditional logic for justification.

Comment: I have ended up using a combination of `pack` and `sprintf` only using the latter when I require formatting within the column

Answer (score 0):

Template Toolkit can do a serviceable job at creating fixed width formatted files. The trick is to use the templates to describe the file and record structure, but have a Perl function format the data for each field.

It may be easier to skip the templates and do all the formatting in Perl. Either way you need to consider how you need to format your fields. In my experience `sprintf` is better and handling more of the formatting cases required by fixed width formatted files. You will probably still need to implement a few helper functions the hand oddities (like EBCDIC/COBOL signed numbers encoded in ASCII, if your unlucky enough).

There are a thousand odd special cases in legacy fixed width formatted files, it's almost enough to make me like XML data files, typically it's the oddest special case in the end that determines what the best method for formatting the file is.